# Primary Key issues when inserting value with SQLite using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am currently trying to have a server that is using SQLite Data bases. In one of my table, I need to INSERT a new value. The PRIMARY KEY will be writen by a user of my application. The problem is that I am trying to figure out how to make sure the guy does not insert an existing value.

I am trying not to use a SELECT to look if the PRIMARY KEY exists, but I don't know how to do that with Node.js. I am trying to make a function that just return `true` or `false` depending on if the thing exist or not.

There is what I got after all my attempts:

```
  function Validation(DataBase){
      console.log('Validation...')
      var sqlCode = "SELECT My_PRIMARY_KEY UserEntry FROM UsersTable WHERE My_PRIMARY_KEY = ?"

      DataBase.get(sqlCode, [UserEntry], (err, row) => {
        if(err){
          return console.error(err.message);
        }

        return false // This is where I tried to return true or false
      });

 }
```

I will also try in the future to return What I selected and all informations I found confused me. If someone can help me on that as well.

Comment: If you try to insert a new row using a value for the primary key that already exists, it'll fail.

Comment: I know and the server stops